# How to use sqlplus with a heredoc and file substitution args

Tags: bash, sqlplus, heredoc

So, I am trying to apply some default configurations to every invocation of `sqlplus` by wrapping the script to be executed in a "header" and "footer" so that I get consistent execution.

However, as I implement this bash function, I realize that some of the scripts have parameters and, when I try to pass them to `sqlplus` when using a heredoc for the "wrapping", sqlplus gets confused and thinks the params meant for the substitution are actual for it (sqlplus).

So, short of creating a temporary file, is there a way to still use a heredoc (or any stdin stream like `envsubst`) along with script params?

code below (either source it in a file or simply copy&paste the function into your interactive shell):

```bash
function exec_sql_file(){
  local sql_file=${1:?You must supply and sql_file file to execute}
  local script_dir username password
  script_dir=$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd)
  source "${script_dir}/omc.env"

  local script="${script_dir}/sql/${sql_file}"

  sqlplus -s "$username/$password@sredb1_high" <<-EOF "${@:2}" | tail -n "+$#"
        set heading off;
        set feedback off;
        set linesize 10000;
        set newpage NONE;
        set colsep '|'
        $(cat "${script}")
        exit;
        EOF

} && export -f exec_sql_file
```

example.sql:

```
select &1 + &2 from dual
```

intended usage:

```bash
exec_sql_file queries/example.sql 1 3
         4
```

What is need is the `"${@:2}"` after the heredoc

the nominal cli it's trying to execute is:

```
sqlplus -s "$username/$password@sredb1_high" @sql/queries/example.sql 1 3
```

here is a working functional example with a temp file (not my preference)

```bash
function exec_sql_file(){
  local sql_file=${1:?You must supply and sql_file file to execute}
  local script_dir username password
  script_dir=$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd)
  local env_file="${script_dir}/omc.env"

  source "${script_dir}/omc.env"

  local script="${script_dir}/sql/${sql_file}"

  local tmpFile
  tmpFile=$(mktemp)
  cat <<-EOF > "${tmpFile}"
        set heading off;
        set feedback off;
        set linesize 10000;
        set newpage NONE;
        set colsep '|'
        $(cat "${script}")
        exit;
        EOF
  echo exit | sqlplus -s "$username/$password@sredb1_high" "@${tmpFile}" "${@:2}" |
    tail -n "+$#" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
} && export -f exec_sql_file
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You're putting `"${@:2}"` in the command-line arguments, why shouldn't it be treated as arguments to the command? How are they supposed to be used instead?

Comment: Remove all spaces before your last `EOF`.

Comment: @Cyrus They used `<<-EOF`. That means it can be indented with tabs.

Comment: I will update the example with something that would work without any table structure. The use of `<<-EOF` and it's allowance for tabs makes no difference, but I'll make that clearer

Comment: a shebang is entirely unneeded. Source it from a file or literally copy&paste it into your interactive shell

Comment: What do you mean by arguments "for the substitution"? The behavior you're seeing, of passing `"${@:2}"` to sqlplus, is 100% correct. Redirections, _including_ redirections from heredocs, can be placed at any location inside a command -- `<input cmd arg1`, `<input cmd arg1`, and `cmd arg1 <input` are all precisely identical.

Comment: Remember, a heredoc **doesn't turn into an argument** -- it only changes where stdin is redirected from. If you want to inject an argument with the heredoc's content, you should be using a parameter expansion instead.

Comment: ...mind, you _can_ refer to a heredoc that was redirected to stdin with `/dev/fd/0`, if you're on an OS that provides that feature.

Answer (score 1):

A heredoc changes where stdin is directed from. It does not act as or turn into a command-line argument, so the idea of putting an argument after a heredoc (or before a heredoc, for that matter) does not make any sense: heredocs do not participate in command-line argument ordering.

I suspect you may want something like:

```
buildArgs() {
  printf '%s\n' \
    'set heading off;' \
    'set feedback off;' \
    'set linesize 10000;' \
    'set newpage NONE;' \
    "set colsep '|'" \
  cat -- "$script"
  printf '%s\n' \
    'exit'
}


sqlplus -s "$username/$password@sredb1_high" "@"<(buildArgs) "${@:2}" |
  tail -n "+$#" |
  sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

...where `"@"<(buildArgs)` is (on Linux -- this differs across platforms) replaced by the shell with something like `@/dev/fd/63`, where `/dev/fd/63` is a filename from which the output of `buildArgs` can be read.

(Note that this is a FIFO, so it can only be read *once*; if you need it to be seekable, this calls for a separate solution; zsh has built-in syntax in the form of `=(buildArgs)`, but this feature is not to my knowledge currently available in bash).

Comment: Is this not, effectively, the same as a temp file, since it created `/dev/fd/xx` ? I mean, I don't have to manage it, but you did give me some other ideas

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno, `/dev/fd` isn't a real filesystem; _all_ open file descriptors exist there. In practice on Linux it's a link to `/proc/self/fd`, which like all of procfs is completely synthetic. Thus: `/dev/fd/0` refers to your stdin, `/dev/fd/1` refers to your stdout, `/dev/fd/2` refers to your stderr; if you call `open()` and it returns FD 3, then there's automatically a `/dev/fd/3`. Indeed, on Linux, if you `ls -l /dev/stdout`, you'll something that refers to `/dev/fd/1` or `/proc/self/fd/1`, which are ultimately both the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I you run from a Linux type shell. To use variables in your heredoc, just set your variable in the shell and put your variable in the heredoc. The shell will expand the variable before sending the data to sqlplus
eg

```
GRP_NAME="2024-03-01"

sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit 1
conn / as sysdba
SET DEFINE ON
PROMPT DROP RESTORE POINT ${GRP_NAME}
drop restore point ${GRP_NAME};
exit
EOF
```